# What's the difference between "attribute" and "property" in restkit

Tags: ios, restkit

I am new for iOS RestKit framework. I have read the document and still can not figure out the differences between "attribute" and "property" in RestKit.

Since in the document, there are

`- addPropertyMappingsFromArray:`

and

`– addAttributeMappingsFromArray:`

I know that while assigning relationship, I should use the first one. However, I still cannot truly understand the differences.

Comment: I agree. I appreciate @kurige for his explanation. Please mark his answer accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just ran into this myself. The naming could definitely be clearer.

`- addAttributeMappingsFromArray:` refers to what you would expect: mappings of class attributes. `- addPropertyMappingsFromArray:` on the other hand refers to `RKPropertyMapping` objects.

If you take a look at the RestKit source you'll see that all the 'addAttributeMappings' methods are a handy abstraction on top of the 'addPropertyMappings' methods, and take care of constructing the required `RKPropertyMapping` objects for you.